# Facebook - Is it possible to retrieve user public profile picture without creating an application?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, web, facebook-opengraph

To clarify:
I'm using the open graph meta tags (`og:video` etc') to create a link that when shared will display an alternate content, in my case a small flash widget. something like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://soundcloud.com/likasumbudee/drums-drums) (soundcloud.com)

I used facebook tool to debug my link and the share part works fine.

My question is: can I get the src for the user profile picture on the page where the widget was shared on?

Comment: Thanks for all the reply, but the question remains ... how do I know the user name? I mean, if I post this link on someone wall I need a way to pass the user_name param to the app

Answer (score 2):

The profile picture is a public object, and you can retrieve it like this:
http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture
e.g:
http://graph.facebook.com/shlomi.schwartz/picture

Comment: please see my comment on the original question

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

You can render the current profile photo for any object by adding the suffix /picture to the object URL. For example, this will render your public profile photo:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/username_or_uid/picture"/>
```

You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height): https://graph.facebook.com/username_or_uid/picture?type=large.

Comment: please see my comment on the original question

Answer (score 0):

It may not answer your question, but to get a facebook user's profile picture use the following url format http://graph.facebook.com/_facebook_user_id_or_facebook_user_name_/picture

So as long as you have a facebook user id or user name (through scraping or other means) you could generate an image src.

Comment: You missed out the USERID like in the other answer.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by scraping?

Comment: Well if you can go through the code on the page with the widget and find the facebook username or facebook user id in the html then you can form the facebook profile pic. I don't see a primary facebook profile pic on your example (soundcloud). Do you have another example?